# More efficient methods for conditional indexing

Tags: r

I work with old census data and need to define the family occupation that should equal that of the head of the household. My solution was to combine the parish number and the house number into a unique family identifier, and then run a function that does the job. It works fine, but on the actual dataset, it is very slow. I've created a test database and a simplified function below. Is there a more efficient alternative for what I'm doing here?

```
test<- NULL
test$RecID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
test$Parish <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
test$House <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2)
test$Relation <- c("Head", "Wife", "Child", "Head", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Head", "Servant", 
                       "Head", "Child", 'Child', 'Head', 'Child', 'Servant')
test$Rela <- c(1,2,3,1,3,3,3,1,4,1,3,3,1,3,4)
test$Occode <- c(1,2,5,2,1,3,4,4,4,1,1,3,2,4,1)
test <- as.data.frame(test)
# solution
test$hh <- paste(test$Parish, '.', test$House)
test$hh <- test$hh %>% str_replace_all(("\\s*"), "")
occup <- function(x){
  house <- test %>% filter(hh == x)
  head <- house %>% filter(Rela == 1)
  occ <- head$Occode
  house %>% mutate(H_Occ = occ)
}
list <- test$hh %>% unique()
bind_rows(lapply(list, occup))
```

Comment: _"My solution was to combine the parish number and the house number into a unique family identifier"_ - what happens if a house gets sold to a new family?

Comment: This is R, and the data is a simplified census record.  A census is done at a single point in time, and what happens next is another issue.

Comment: If you compute `unique` values outside the function you would save time.

Answer (score 2):

We could join the data to a version of itself that just "sees" the Parish, House, and Occupation of the Head of household. Filters and joins are fast so this should be faster than the original approach, especially on larger data.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  left_join(test %>%
    filter(Relation == "Head") %>%
    select(Parish, House, Occode_head = Occode)
  )
```

Result

```
Joining, by = c("Parish", "House")
   RecID Parish House Relation Rela Occode  hh Occode_head
1      1      1     1     Head    1      1 1.1           1
2      2      1     1     Wife    2      2 1.1           1
3      3      1     1    Child    3      5 1.1           1
4      4      1     2     Head    1      2 1.2           2
5      5      1     2    Child    3      1 1.2           2
6      6      1     2    Child    3      3 1.2           2
7      7      1     3    Child    3      4 1.3           4
8      8      1     3     Head    1      4 1.3           4
9      9      1     3  Servant    4      4 1.3           4
10    10      2     1     Head    1      1 2.1           1
11    11      2     1    Child    3      1 2.1           1
12    12      2     1    Child    3      3 2.1           1
13    13      2     2     Head    1      2 2.2           2
14    14      2     2    Child    3      4 2.2           2
15    15      2     2  Servant    4      1 2.2           2
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! It's much faster than my original code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much faster this is, but:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  group_by(Parish, House) %>% 
  mutate(H_occ = Occode[Relation == "Head"])
```